# Moving an image into a div, and having text wrap around

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web-applications

So I have been scouring the inter webs and various JavaScript site, along with looking through the JavaScript language and apis as well. my end goal is to be able to have a dragable image much like JQuery's drag and drop into a div full of text and having text wrap around it. Is there a library or a api that has this functionally or somewhere to jump off? I am currently using JQuery's sortable to help with moving divs but just lack the ability to move images within the divs.

Thank you for your time,
-D

just for reference,
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets

Comment: is there a way much like TinyMCE (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) where in a text area JavaScript can detect which line i am on? If so then i could do the sort of click to edit and drag a picture and it will snap to line. i am using jeditable (http://www.appelsiini.net/jeditable) for my on the fly text editing area as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using an editor like CkEditor or TinyMCE then combine it with jquery drag/drop functionality.

On drop trigger the appropriate editor event to add the image at the caret point.

Comment: I like your idea, i am currently using http://www.appelsiini.net/jeditable for my on the fly text editing in place, hate to ask another question but is there a way much like TinyMCE where in a text area JavaScript can detect which line i am on? If so then i could do the sort of click to edit and drag a picture and it will snap to line.

Answer (score 0):

might be able to cook up some sort of jqueryui draggable/droppable & [jqslickwrap](http://jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/) hybrid

Comment: Not too worried about the actual wrapping, because the picture size and overall shape is unknown and doesn't matter. I am more looking forward to moving the image and it not just being a floating div which adds no usability.

Answer (score 0):

I found that an interesting thing for my blog and made some trails and errors. if anyone could make a jquery plugin from it?!
Images and text should be inside a div. See it working [here](http://www.meindesign.net/tools/running_text.php).

1.Words don't have coordinates, so you have to wrap each word with a html-tag. This increase the text a lot!!!

```
var text=$('div#text').text();
var arr=text.split(" ");
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   arr[i]="<span id='t'>"+arr[i]+"</span>";
   }
text=arr.join(" ");
$('div#text').html(function(){return text;});
```

2.Place your image.
3.Get the coordinates and size of the div for the image and declare some vars .

```
var temp=$("div#img");
var pos=temp.offset();
var imgleft=parseInt(pos.left);
var imgtop=parseInt(pos.top);
var imgwidth=temp.width();
var imgheight=temp.height();
var latesttop=$("div#text").offset().top;
var spanleft,spantop,spanwidth,spanheight,latestleft,latestwidth;
```

4.Walk through each word tag. Find word which protrude into the image. Calculate the distance from the end of the word before to the right edge of the image and place a div with the specific width as a place holder.

```
$("span#t").each(function(index){
            pos=$(this).offset();
            spanleft=parseInt(pos.left);
            spantop=parseInt(pos.top);
            spanwidth=$(this).width();
            spanheight=$(this).height();
            if(spantop+spanheight>imgtop 
            && spantop<imgtop+imgheight 
            && spanleft+spanwidth>imgleft
            && spanleft<imgleft+imgwidth){
              if(latesttop!=spantop){ 
                latestleft=0;
                latestwidth=0;
                }
              var spacewidth=15+imgwidth+imgleft-latestleft-latestwidth;
              $(this).before("<div id='t' style='display:inline-block;width:"+spacewidth+"px'></div>");
              }
            latesttop=spantop;  
            latestleft=spanleft;
            latestwidth=spanwidth;     
            });
```

5.Clean text from word wraps when finished.

```
$('span#t').replaceWith(function(){
            return $(this).contents();
            });
```